# Run a command from Windows from Python code

Tags: python, c++, windows

How can I run the following command from Python3 on Windows 7

```
gcc main.cpp -o main.out 
./main.out
```

The purpose is to execute the main.cpp file from Python3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look [subprocess call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["gcc", "main.cpp -o main.out"])
subprocess.run(["./main.out"])
```

should work. But subprocess have more utilities that will be usefull for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have a compile time error, because I need to link the some .lib files.I can compile in VS because I add the .lib files in the Linker-> Input. So do you know how can I see the cmd Visual Studio uses to compile and execute my code ?

Comment: Sorry but I alwais use Linux for programing and I only know the basics about cmd. But subprocces module have options to manage the output, and yo can link the libs withs gcc from the cmd, try -I or -l option.

Comment: The argument needs to be either `["gcc", "main.cpp", "-o", "main.out"]` or `"gcc main.cpp -o main.out"`. Otherwise `subprocess.list2cmdline` creates the incorrect command line `gcc "main.cpp -o main.out"`.